# Updating profile image

Tags: java, android

So basically since updating my gradle settings I have been unable to change the profile pic in my profile of my app.

When I click on the image it should let me select a new pic from my stored images which it does do however when i click on the image it then tries to change on the profile but does not. I also have it linked to Firebase and it does upload to it so i do know that that part is working fine it is only the part that where the image is suppose to change on the profile that is not working.

Code for uploading to firebase:

```
 private void uploadImageToFirebaseStorage() {
    StorageReference profileImageRef =
            FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("profilepics/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

    if (uriProfileImage != null) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        profileImageRef.putFile(uriProfileImage)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        profileImageUrl = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

code for changing profile pic:

```
 private void showImageChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Profile Image"), CHOOSE_IMAGE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CHOOSE_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        uriProfileImage = data.getData();
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uriProfileImage);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            uploadImageToFirebaseStorage();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

code for image:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showImageChooser();
        }
    });

    loadUserInformation();
```

Gradle:

```
dependencies {

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'


implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'


implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'

implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'

implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

Comment: All the code I have was working fine until I updated settings in gradle

Comment: I've updated the SDK version from 26 to 27 and updated the android.support settings and firebase settings

Comment: I'm getting no errors in the code since updating it is just the profile pic that does not change anymore. I am wondering is it because I am using SDK 27 when my android phone is 26?

Comment: Should I maybe revert back to older settings then and try again?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Add this code inside the `onActivityResult` Method and try

```
Uri resultUri = data.getData();
StorageReference filepath = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("profile_images").child(System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

filepath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(AddDeviceActivity.this, "Your Image Uploaded!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        final String downloadUrl = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();
                        UserRef.child("profileimage").setValue(downloadUrl)
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                            //when success
                                        }else {
                                            //when failed

                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                }
```

Comment: getting quite a few errors with that such as result.getUri() and UserRef.child

Comment: UserRef is Database reference if you storing that image url.

Comment: Still not working! When i click on image the load symbol goes round as if it is updating it however it does not change. Weird as it still uploads to firebase just does not show properly on app

Comment: Without using Bitmap try to using `Picasso` or `Glide` like image caching library